# Android Development in Eclipse: New layouts are small

Tags: android, eclipse

I've tried finding the answer to this but none of my searches have found useful info.

Anyway, usually when I add new layouts they're just fine, but sometimes eclipse will start making the new layouts about half-sized and will make me restart the program to get it working. I was wondering if anybody could tell me if it's something I'm doing wrong and how to resolve the issue.

Here's an image to show you what I mean.
[image: small layout]

Comment: make sure your target is not android-w of api level 20

Comment: just change Device type from the upper tab....
"Android Wear Square"

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered, I got it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your selection from `Android Wear Square` to  something else and also change `android-w of api level 20` to the one without `w`.
`W` is for the Android Wear...the Google Watches
SEE HERE [ANDROID WEAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Wear)

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

it is because you are using `Android Wear Square` layout :)

Answer (score 1):

You are developing for Android-wear. It is the watch and it's small:D Change it to some Google or Generic phone or tablet.

Answer (score 0):

at the TOP side of you graphical layout screen...there is OPTION for Device screen selection in Configuration chooser...

Look here for more help [Eclipse ADT](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html)

you have selected "Android wear Round" screen that may be around 2.7"

Instead of that select "Nexus One".. which screen size is 3.7" (480 x 800 hdpi) it will set your layout to bigger size... OR YOU CAN SELECT OTHER ONE TOO

Changing a device screen can make difference...

[image]

**You Can See All Screen Previews By Checking "Preview All Screens"...**
It will give you all listed screen previews as per their dimensions so you can see that how your application looks on different screen...